# Firebase retrieve data from 2 levels in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime database into a table called "joueur" but i have the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.florian.fichiertexteandbddtest1, PID: 899
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.florian.fichiertexteandbddtest1.Joueur

My Firebase Realtime Database is this one:[firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XNAK.png)

I'm trying to get the value of joueurs inside the children of tables Joueurs

Here is my code to retrieve the data and add it to the table:

```
int i;
            for (i=0;i<150;i++) {
                firebaseReference2.child(String.valueOf(i));
                firebaseReference2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot keyNode : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                            Joueur joueur = keyNode.getValue(Joueur.class);
                            databaseHelper.addJoueur(joueur.getNom_joueur(), joueur.getPrenom_joueur(), joueur.getNum_licence_joueur(), joueur.getId_equipe_joueur());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(EquipeActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

The error is on Joueur joueur = keyNode.getValue(Joueur.class);

Also my Joueur class:
`public class Joueur implements Serializable {

```
private String nom_joueur;
private String prenom_joueur;
private int num_licence_joueur;
private int id_equipe_joueur;
private int id;


public Joueur() {
}

public Joueur(String nom_joueur, String prenom_joueur, int num_licence_joueur, int id_equipe_joueur, int id) {
    this.nom_joueur = nom_joueur;
    this.prenom_joueur = prenom_joueur;
    this.num_licence_joueur = num_licence_joueur;
    this.id_equipe_joueur = id_equipe_joueur;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNom_joueur() {
    return nom_joueur;
}

public void setNom_joueur(String nom_joueur) {
    this.nom_joueur = nom_joueur;
}

public String getPrenom_joueur() {
    return prenom_joueur;
}

public void setPrenom_joueur(String prenom_joueur) {
    this.prenom_joueur = prenom_joueur;
}

public int getNum_licence_joueur() {
    return num_licence_joueur;
}

public void setNum_licence_joueur(int num_licence_joueur) {
    this.num_licence_joueur = num_licence_joueur;
}

public int getId_equipe_joueur() {
    return id_equipe_joueur;
}

public void setId_equipe_joueur(int id_equipe_joueur) {
    this.id_equipe_joueur = id_equipe_joueur;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}`

Thank you!

Comment: How is your "firebaseReference2" object defined?

Comment: I defined it like this : firebaseReference2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Joueurs"); So it would read the data from table Joueurs

Comment: And you want to get the data that exists under `Joueurs` node and all sub-nodes, right?

Comment: Only from sub-nodes, i only want to get the data needed to create a player, so id_equipe_joueur, nom_joueur, prenom_joueur, num_licence_joueur

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get the data according to your database schema, you need to loop through the "DataSnapshot" object using ".getChildren()" twice, as explained in the following lines of code:

```
firebaseReference2.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot firstLevelSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot secondLevelSnapshot : firstLevelSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = secondLevelSnapshot.getKey();
                    keys.add(key);
                    Joueur joueur = secondLevelSnapshot.getValue(Joueur.class);
                    databaseHelper.addJoueur(
                        joueur.getNom_joueur(),
                        joueur.getPrenom_joueur(),
                        joueur.getNum_licence_joueur(),
                        joueur.getId_equipe_joueur()
                    );
                    Log.d(TAG, secondLevelSnapshot.getNom_joueur());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result of the above code will be the passing of each "Joueur" object to the "addJoueur()" method and in the logcat you'll see the following output:

```
ccu
...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I thought about doing the same but didn't know the method addOnCompleteListener :'(

Comment: It worked at first but now i have the error : com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int and it point the line Joueur joueur= secondLevelSnapshot.getValue(Joueur.Class)

Comment: Do all the parameters of the Joeuurs class have to be Strings?

Comment: The fact that you are getting another error, means that the initial error disappeared and this is good news :) but this sounds like a new issue which basically should be considered another question because it cannot be answered in a comment. As a personal guess, most likely you have a property in the database that holds a String and you are trying to convert it to an int, which is not possible in Java, but in order to follow the rules of this community, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: *Do all the parameters of the Joeuurs class have to be Strings?* No, each parameter should of the type you need.